# How to call multiple services (in sequence) for each request using ZUUL API Gateway?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-zuul

I want to call a service to Validate(Validation service) before routing the actual request to desired service.

Lets consider two different scenarios:

- If the Validation service returns Valid, then call respective service (In this case service A).
  [image: Valid request scenario]
- If Validation service returns Invalid, then return response bad request to user (No need to call service A)

[image]

**Please help me finding correct configuration (or coding in which filter) to be done, to call validation service for every request.**

Comment: If you are using spring, you can use a interceptor that will do the validation and decide whether the request proceeds or not

Comment: @SherifelKhatib, Thanks for helping hand. Can interceptor route to other external services also. I don't want to code on gateway itself.

Comment: I think one can write a pre filter , where u can call the validation service . if the validation service , returns valid , then u can actually route to the service , if it does not , then there will be something u can set in the request context, due to which u can stop the routing and return a response

Comment: @indraneel, As of now i am doing the same. To call my external validation service, i am forming new http request in PRE FILTER and calling it. **Is there any other good way to achieve the same**

Comment: I don't think there is anything in terms of configuration one can do , for ur use case . https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1027 . You can look at this link , u can just implement a spring MVC controller and do what u want above

Comment: Although there is really no difference to what u are doing right now with the pre filter with the above approach.

Comment: For ur use case , the reactive stack will be a better option, please look at spring webflux.